# Angular 2 enable submit button for type="file"

Tags: angular

I am using a form which has certain required fields with validation, the problem I am facing is, even after uploading a File which is a required field for enabling the Save(Submit) button, I am not able to enable save. Am I missing anything?

This is what I am using in HTML:

```
<input id="chooseFileFile"
       type="file"
       accept="{{fileTypes}}"
       class="btn btn-secondary br-choose-file"
       (change)="onFileChange($event)"
       [disabled]="currentAsset.IsClientAsset"
       ngControl="assetUpload"
       #assetUpload="ngForm"
       required
>
```